# Can't invoke pip.main in python

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pip modules automatically:

```
try:
    import paramiko
except ImportError:
    import pip
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        print('Method 1')
        pip.main(['install', 'paramiko'])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', 'paramiko'])

    import paramiko
```

But it doesn't work in this environment:

- Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- pip 19.2.3 from c:\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

And the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invoke-pip.py", line 4, in <module>
    import paramiko
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "invoke-pip.py", line 11, in <module>
    pip._internal.main(['install', 'paramiko'])
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute '_internal'
```

What should I use?

Comment: "I'm trying to install pip modules automatically"—ugh, please don't do this. Declare your dependencies and let me install them, or build a package.

Comment: perhaps you could just use a [requirements file?](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/)

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you are catching the wrong Exception. `ImportError` was in python 2.x and from python 3.x it has been renamed to `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Here is the fixed code for the same

```py
try:
    import paramiko
except (ImportError, ModuleNotFoundError): # This will handle both for python 2.x and 3.x
    import pip
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        print('Method 1')
        pip.main(['install', 'paramiko'])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', 'paramiko'])

    import paramiko
```

As @Chris said, declare a requirements.txt file and let the users install packages. This will ensure the exact version of package is installed that is used while the development of your program.